# Flutter- How do exit the textfield in a multiline textfield?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to have a multiline textfield where some paragraph data can be returned. I changed the 'new line' button to 'done' button using the textInputAction property, and though it calls onEditingComplete, it is still not exiting the textfield. I know it has something to do with focus but i am not able to figure out exactly how to do it.

This is my code

```
TextField(
              onChanged: (text){
                print('On changed is called');
              },
              onEditingComplete: (){
                print('Editing is done ');
              },
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              maxLines: 6 ,

              controller: textEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  .....
              )
          ),
```

How can i de-focus on pressing done? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you asigned a FocusNode to the Textfield, at `onSubmitted:` use `myFocusNode.unfocus()`but, to be honest, that's kind of weird, it should unfocus itself when "done" is pressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) to control the focus.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() {
    return _MyWidget();
  }
}
class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
  FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          maxLines: 8,
          autofocus:false ,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          onEditingComplete: () {
            print("edit");
            _focusNode.unfocus();
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried this , however it is still not working! It does not do anything on clicking the done button

Comment: @Denise updated my answer to show all of my code that works well on my machine(iPhone Simulator). Please check the difference between this and yours.

Comment: Thanks...figured out my mistake..I hadn't written the initState function properly and the  _focusnode variable got nested in some other function. This solution worked nicely thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to set `keyboardType` to `text` and `textInputAction` to `done` for `maxLines>1`

```
  maxLines: 3,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```

Comment: In this case there is no "New line" button, so you either have "done" button or the "new line", bot not the both :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make maxLine: null as shown below

```
new TextFormField(
           controller: controller,
           obscureText: obscure,
           focusNode: _focusNode,
           maxLines: null,
           keyboardType: inputtype,
           onSaved: (String val) {
             text = val;
           },
           decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: hintText,
               enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
               focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
               labelStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xFF0C0738))),
         )
```

Comment: Adding maxLine helps in wrapping the text however it is not returning and exiting the textfield  on pressing done

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it at the `onSubmitted:` method?

```
TextField(
  focusNode: myFocus,
  onSubmitted: (text) {
    myFocus.unfocus();
  },
),
```

Comment: Hi.. i tried this however when i try this the keyboard is typing without the textfield being in focus at all.. and then the keyboard doesnt go back either

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has a problem. It mandates that you use `TextInputAction.done` which seriously limits the functionality of multiline `TextFormField`. A simple solution is to use a focusNode along with a `toggle`. The toggle is activated when the form field gets focus.

Assuming that the top level elements are children of the same column, something like below would suffice

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    focusNode.hasFocus
        ? FlatButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FaIcon(
                  Icons.done,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Done',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              });
            },
          )
        : Text(''),
  ],
),

Card(
  child: TextFormField(
    focusNode: focusNode, // The focusNode should be properly initiated and disposed
    controller: jobSpecificsController,
    maxLines: 3,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    decoration: formElementDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Please enter the job details.'),
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {}); // Without this setState, you won't get the toggle in the iOS.
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

just set       textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,